# Python: Sending email from custom domain

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email from a custom domain in Python. I have figured out how to send emails from other domains, like gmail.com, using smtplib [[example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842922/controlling-the-sender-id-in-sms-packets)]. Now I want to figure out how to send an email from a custom domain like catsareonwheels.com.

I thought I would be able to use [smtpd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html) to send emails from a server, but that library appears only to serve as a proxy fora [Mail Transfer Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). From what I can tell, there *are* MTA's written in Pure Python [e.g. [Slimta](https://github.com/slimta/python-slimta)], but I have not been able to find any examples of snippets that actually demonstrate how to send an email from a custom domain with Python.

If anyone can help point me toward literature that might help me determine how best to achieve this goal, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

TO SEND AN EMAIL FROM A CUSTOM DOMAIN, YOU DO THE FOLLOWING:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = "<your_mail_account>"
msg["To"] = "<destiny_account>"
body_text = "HOLA MUNDO :)"
body_part = MIMEText(body_text, 'plain')
msg.attach(body_part)
with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.<CUSTOM_DOMAIN>.com", port=587) as smtp_obj:  # ENVIAR DESDE UN DOMINIO PERSONALIZADO.
    smtp_obj.ehlo()
    smtp_obj.starttls()
    smtp_obj.ehlo()
    smtp_obj.login("<your_mail_account>", "<your_password>")
    smtp_obj.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To'],], msg.as_string())

print("¡Datos enviados con éxito!")
```

That's all :) Hope you like it!

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the SMTP server settings that I have found on other posts I have found the right settings browsing through domain cPanel:

1. Go to "List Email Accounts"
2. On the right sido of the account you want to use click on "Connect devices"[image]

3. Check "Mail Client Manual Settings"

Answer (score -2):

What do you exactly mean by "custom domain"?
If you have some hosting witch provides you an email service then you can use smtplib as well.

Lets say I bought a hosting and a domain use-smtplib.com. I've created an email account myname@use-smtplib.com in admin panel.
Then configuration should look somehow like this:

```
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.use-smtplib.com', '465') as smtp:

        smtp.login('myname@use-smtplib.com', 'my_strong_password')

        subject = "Message from python"
        msg = "Hello from python"

        smtp.sendmail('myname@use-smtplib.com', 'recipient@gmail.com', msg)
```

Exact configuration may be different depending on your email provider. Domains starting with mail.domain.com and smtp.domain.com are pretty common.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Maybe I'm overthinking this. Do you have a good reference on how to create an email account with Python? By custom domain I just mean a domain I'm renting from some domain vendor like GoDaddy.

Comment: OK, it looks like you don't entirely know how email works. In a nutshell you need not only domain but also, a mailserver. Go ahead and dig deeper. I could explain it to you in details but it's going to be a big off topic here.

Comment: Are you aware of an example that shows how to create a user and send an email with a Python mailserver? I'm reading the standards (e.g. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2342.txt) but haven't seen any ready-to-roll examples in Python yet...

Comment: The problem is not in python. Python only communicates with existing mailserver. Buying a domain name is not equivalent of having access to mailserver. If you bring godaddy as example you have to buy also an email service (go to their website for more info).

Comment: Excellent, this is helping to clarify. But say I want to build my own mailserver. Do you know of any absolutely minimal mailserver examples written in a scripting language other than perl?

Comment: Excellent, this is helping to clarify. But say I want to build my own mailserver. Do you know of any absolutely minimal mailserver examples written in a scripting language other than perl?

Comment: Install and setup Exim4 or Postfix on your computer/server/virtual machine.